# Source code location in Chromium that handles Javascript XHR requests?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, chromium

I have the Chromium project set up on my PC using Visual Studio 2017.  Everything compiles and runs fine.  I am looking for the source code location that handles XHR requests made by Javascript code running in a page loaded into the browser.  Does anyone know what project or source file contains that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/xmlhttprequest/ shows where the XHR sources are in the Chromium/Blink tree.

So in your clone of the repo, that’s in `src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/xmlhttprequest`

Comment: Thanks.  I set breakpoints on the constructor for the xmlhttprequest class for that file, and many of the more important class methods (sendBytesData(), etc.).  I then loaded a page that I know does several XHR requests, confirming the execution of those requests with the DevTools debugger Network window.  None of the breakpoints were ever hit.

Answer (score 1):

As of May 2020, the correct link is:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/99b8c9800ac123eddc3e199088d22569c5294b22/Source/core/xml/XMLHttpRequest.cpp

I was interested in this myself to see what happens to the connection when the XHR request times out.